# Загрузка файлов на GitHub

Tags: c#, github, git-commit

c# Необходимо проверить, существует ли файл в папке с программой в моём репозитории на гитхабе (если есть, удалить), а после, этот текстовый файл загрузить на гитхаб. (Другими словами, нужно как-то обновить тот файл, что сейчас существует на гитхабе)

```
var client = new GitHubClient(new ProductHeaderValue("GitHub"));
var basicAuth = new Credentials("login", "password");
client.Credentials = basicAuth;
var tokenAuth = new Credentials("token");
client.Credentials = tokenAuth;
```

Comment: https://developer.github.com/v3/

Answer (score 2):

Склонируй репозиторий - `git clone [your repo]`
Посмотри что тебе нужно  - в редакторе/терминале удали или добавь что нужно Забрось на гит -
`git add .`  -

`git commit -m " Your new commit "`

`git push origin master`

Ecли я тебя правильно понял то это все.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Если кому-то ещё пригодится, почитайте вот эту документацию: https://octokitnet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started/

Comment: Пытался сейчас кое-как написать. По итогу, дальше подключения к своему аккаунту не зашёл. В посте написал, что у меня сейчас написано в коде

Comment: Автору нужно сделать это на C#, а не в консоли.

Comment: Да. Мне нужно написать этот код в консольном приложении c#

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, а что, c# не научили запускать другие процессы?

Comment: Ну так напишите, как это сделать на C#, запустив другой процесс.